# angular 5 server side rendering when i run npm run serve:universal error TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular5

when I run this command npm run serve: universal I got error TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined.

[image: Logs]

Comment: it's look like you has a variable undefined. when you declare it, use `variable:string=""`

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks for replying me .....this issue in dist/server.js file how can we edit dis/server.js file